# How to flip each GridView cell on touch and show another image?

Tags: android, animation, gridview

In my app i need to perform flip animation on cells of Grid View to show another image when user touches. initially i have populated grid view with images when user touches them they should flip and some other image is shown to user.Thanks in advance.
this is my adapter class:-

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mycontext;
public Integer[] picids = {
        R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2, R.drawable.pic_3,
        R.drawable.pic_4, R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
        R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8, R.drawable.pic_9
        };

 public Adapter(Context c){
 mycontext = c;    }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return picids.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return picids[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageview =  new ImageView(mycontext);
    imageview.setImageResource(picids[position]);
    imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120,120));      
    return imageview  ;
}
```

}

and following is my main activity class:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    grid.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A relatively hacky way to do this would be to use [JazzyListView](https://github.com/twotoasters/jazzylistview), and "grab" an animation out of the source and implement it in your onClick listener to trigger an animation event.

Comment: how can I use JazzyListVew for a GridVIew ? for set animation for any cell in a column while scrolling GridView . Please Help me . Thanks :)